# How do I write a recursive function for a combination

Tags: java, recursion, discrete-mathematics

I am going over recursive functions and i understand how to write basic ones, but I have a question on my study guide that I dont understand.

.   Write code for a recursive function named Combinations that computes nCr. Assume that nCr can be computed as follows:

```
nCr = 1 if r = 0 or if r = n and
nCr = (n-1)C(r-1) + (n-1)Cr
```

Can someone please help me through this or explain in layman's terms? Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question really has all the information. It tells you how to compute nCr - and that a lot of the time, you compute it by computing another nCr (with smaller arguments).  So your functions might look like this:

```
int nCr(n, r) {
  if (r == 0 || r == n) return 1;  // stop recursion, we know the answer.
  return nCr(n-1, r-1) + nCr(n-1, r); // the answer is made of the sum of two "easier" ones
}
```

That's translating as literally as I can.  Let's see how that works in practice, by computing

```
nCr(4,2)
= nCr(4-1, 2-1) + nCr(4-1, 2)
= nCr(3, 1) + nCr(3, 2)
= nCr(3-1, 1) + nCr(3-1,0) + nCr(3-1, 2-1) + nCr(3-1, 2)
= nCr(2, 1) + nCr(2,0) + nCr(2,1) + nCr(2,2)
= nCr(1, 0) + nCr(1,1) + 1 + nCr(1,0) + nCr(1,1) + 1
= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
= 6
```

Of course we knew that already:

```
nCr(4,2) = (4 * 3) / (2 * 1) = 6
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive function includes calls to itself and a termination case

in your example `nCr = 1 if r = 0 or if r = n` forms the termination

and `(n-1)C(r-1) + (n-1)Cr` is the recursion

so your code should look somethink like this

```
int nCR(int n, int r){
    if (r == 0 || r == n){
        return 1; //terminate
    }
    else{
        return nCr(n-1, r-1) + nCr(n-1, r); //recursive calls
    }
}
```