# How can I write a recursive function in R?

Tags: r, recursion, combinations

How can I write a recursive function to obtain the `combination(n,r) = combination(n-1, r-1) + combination(n-1,r)` in R?
I tried the following code but I only get an error message:

```
nCr=function(n, r) {
if (r == 0)
{
if (r == n) {
    
return (1)
} } else {
return (nCr(n-1, r-1) + nCr(n-1, r)) 
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which type of error message do you get? It seems that you try to use the function you define in its definition...

Comment: @Llopis Well,  that kinda **is** the definition of a recursive function!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Related questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485602/how-do-i-write-a-recursive-function-for-a-combination), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906332/how-to-calculate-combination-and-permutation-in-r).

```
nCr <- function(n, r) {
  if (r == 0 | r == n) return (1)
  else return (nCr(n-1, r-1) + nCr(n-1, r)) 
}

nCr(20, 6)
[1] 38760
choose(20, 6)
[1] 38760
```

Note the performance of the built-in function.

```
system.time(for(i in 1:10) nCr(20, 6))
##    user  system elapsed 
##    8.74    0.00    8.90 

system.time(for(i in 1:10) choose(20, 6))
##    user  system elapsed 
##       0       0       0
```

The performance problems partly occur because the function is called with the same inputs many time.  You can make `nCr` faster by caching the results ‐ this technique is useful for many recursive functions, though notice that the built-in function is still much faster.

```
library(memoise)
nCr2 <- memoise(nCr)
system.time(for(i in 1:10) nCr2(20, 6))
##    user  system elapsed 
##    0.88    0.00    0.91
```